Can i use a lower watt charger with my laptop?
I have a surface laptop 2. It came with a Model 1800 charger (44W - Output is 15V 2.58a). I can't find a replacement right now. Can I use the Model 1625 charger (36W - Output 12V 2.58) to charge my laptop or will it fry my laptop? Are there any alternatives that I could use?
Edit: I would like to know if there are alternative chargers that are compatible with my Surface Laptop 2 that I can use instead of the Model 1800 one.

"Will it fry my laptop?" - How would a lower voltage charger fry your laptop? If anything, it simply would fail to charge your laptop. The difference in wattage between those two chargers is pretty significant. What you should be worried about is frying the charger. I would not want to risk potential problems stimming from that situation. There is a higher than 0% chance that by attempting to draw more wattage than the charger can support damage could be done to both the laptop charger.

I read somewhere that it may end up causing problems for my own laptops battery too  hence the "fry" statement. Would going above 44W also be a bad idea then?

You really should only use a charger designed for Surface devices.. Surface laptops using a magnetic  connector.  You should focus on finding a replacement for the original charger.

Would going above 44W also be a bad idea then? ... no ... the output must be 15 V ... and it must have the capacity to supply at least 44 W

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/surface-power-supplies-and-charging-requirements-0d9d51d4-594b-464d-9086-c90f35b80c01

@Ramhound, surface devices have a number of different charger capacities with the exact same connector I believe.  Mokubai just gave a good link.  I personally have 3 surfaces with 2 different "compatible" power supplies that will all "connect" to any of them just fine.  2 laptops, 1 surface pro.  This is a good question I think.

Also.. I am NOT CONDONING IT, but ALL of my power supplies have been used at one time or another to charge every Surface I have.  My wife do what she want.  If they are mismatched, they do indeed "work" but I have found that if I put a smaller supply to push a bigger machine (like the pro) the brick heats up telling me I probably shouldn't do that.  This is 100% anecdotal.  I am sharing my experience because I have a few of these

@music2myear They are different because I would like to know what to do if you can't get the exact charger. If I could find the exact one, I would just get it but so far they are not available where I am. I was hoping to find some information on chargers that are compatible between Microsoft products.

@Mokubai, I've already gone through that link and I can't figure out which of those chargers would work for me.

@SeñorCMasMas You're right the Model 1625 does connect with my laptop and does charge it, I just don't know if the difference in voltages is going to do something.

Asking which chargers are compatible with your device is off topic on this site as it is a hardware shopping request. The linked duplicate answers the underlying question, and also has its own linked duplicate which has further information. That IS the answer to the question you have asked.

Amazon, eBay etc.  don't deliver where I am unfortunately but yeah I am realizing, I am going to have to try and find my specific charger somehow.

Simply based on the numbers you provide, there would be no harm in trying it.  At best, it will charge your laptop slower.  At worst, it wont charge it at all. There is no risk in trying it, as its only a small step down, so there is no risk of overvolting your laptop.
Of course, you should always try to use to proper charger for your device.

@JoepvanSteen read different things?  Its got a lower voltage.  There is no harm at all...

@JoepvanSteen because its true... not to mention, the "This question already has answers here" is MY answer
